# TFS 2010 Team Build Error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I get the following TFS Team Build Error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Builds\17\NextGenIssueTracker\
    NGIT-2011Updates\Binaries\QA\_PublishedWebsites\NGIT.Test.ClientProxy_Package\
    Archive\Content\E_C\Builds\17\NextGenIssueTracker\NGIT-2011Updates\Sources\
    branches\2011Updates\NGIT.Test.ClientProxy\obj\QA\Package'.
```

However, I've removed the project from source control, the solution, and from my local working directory. But I'm still getting this error.

Any suggestions?

**Important:** I don't have access to this 'E:\Builds\17" directory, so that might be a game changer!

Comment: what's the context of this error in TFS?  i.e. what build step are you currently in?

Comment: Along with Nick: If this project is no longer under TFS, what *exactly* are you doing to throw that error?

Comment: I don't believe that I'm doing anything! My local solution builds fine, but the CI triggered build fails with the above error. I have no clue why it still cares about this project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into a limitation on the maximum amount of characters that a path can have.  This is a pretty well known problem with windows.

Some options available:

1. Change the build path to something much shorter than that.
2. Rename the solution and, potentially, projects in the solution to shorten the path.

For all intents and purposes, the first part:

```
 "E:\Builds\17\NextGenIssueTracker\
    NGIT-2011Updates\Binaries\QA\_PublishedWebsites\NGIT.Test.ClientProxy_Package\
    Archive\Content\E_C"
```

is odd.

Sounds like you need to get with your TFS administrator to ask them what the heck that is about.

Comment: Originally, I tried to rename the project. But now I don't even want the project under source control, so I've removed it from source control, removed it from my solution, and deleted it from my working directory

Comment: @ErOx: Then I'm at a complete loss here.  If the project is no longer under source control, exactly what part is TFS playing?

Comment: I don't know. My local solution builds fine, but fails when my CI build is triggered. I have no idea why it still cares about this project.

Comment: @ErOx Try manually triggering a build and override the settings in the dialog box to do a full workspace clean. Looks like you've got some build artifacts still lying around.

Answer (score 1):

Re-entering a comment as an answer since it fixed the problem:

Try manually triggering a build and override the settings in the dialog box to do a full workspace clean. Looks like you've got some build artifacts still lying around.